# How to make a new column with the previous version of a row

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a dataset in R that looks like this:

| ID | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |
| 1 | A2 |
| 2 | A1 |
| 2 | B2 |
| 2 | C3 |
| 2 | C4 |
| 3 | A1 |
| 3 | D4 |
| 3 | C3 |
| 3 | A4 |
| 3 | B2 |
| 4 | A2 |
| 4 | B2 |

I want to create a new column, that consists of the latest version of the tag, placed in the same row as the newest row.

| ID | tags | Last ID mention |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | NA |
| 1 | A2 | NA |
| 2 | A1 | 1 |
| 2 | B2 | NA |
| 2 | C3 | NA |
| 2 | C4 | NA |
| 3 | A1 | 2 |
| 3 | D4 | NA |
| 3 | C3 | 2 |
| 3 | A4 | NA |
| 3 | B2 | 2 |
| 4 | A2 | 1 |
| 4 | B2 | 3 |

Because the number of rows for each ID is different I don't think I can use lag(). I've been mainly working with dplyr and trying some loops but I don't know if that's the tidiest manner to do so. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to group by `tags` and take the lag `ID`.

```r
library(dplyr)
inp %>%
  mutate(`Last ID Mention` = lag(ID, default = NA), .by = tags)
#    ID tags Last ID Mention
# 1   1   A1              NA
# 2   1   A2              NA
# 3   2   A1               1
# 4   2   B2              NA
# 5   2   C3              NA
# 6   2   C4              NA
# 7   3   A1               2
# 8   3   D4              NA
# 9   3   C3               2
# 10  3   A4              NA
# 11  3   B2               2
# 12  4   A2               1
# 13  4   B2               3
```

Base R, in case you're curious:

```r
with(inp, ave(ID, tags, FUN = function(z) c(NA, z[-length(z)])))
#  [1] NA NA  1 NA NA NA  2 NA  2 NA  2  1  3
```

---

Data

```r
inp <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), tags = c("A1", "A2", "A1", "B2", "C3", "C4", "A1", "D4", "C3", "A4", "B2", "A2", "B2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Especially the dplyr version is very clever!